# Can I test kafka-streams suppress logic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My application use kafka streams `suppress` logic.

I want to test kafka streams topology using suppress.

Runnning uinit test, My topology not emit result.

Kafka streams logic

```java
...
.suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Suppressed.BufferConfig.maxBytes(1_000_000_000L).emitEarlyWhenFull()))
...
```

My test case code.
After create input data, running test case cant't read suppress logic output record.
just return `null`

```java
testDriver.pipeInput(recordFactory.create("input", key, dummy, 0L));

System.out.println(testDriver.readOutput("streams-result", Serdes.String().deserializer(), serde.deserializer()));
```

Can i test my suppress logic?

Comment: Compare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480927/how-to-unit-test-a-kafka-stream-application-that-uses-session-window

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is yes.

Some good references are [Confluent Example Tests](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/window/CustomWindowTest.java) this example in particular tests the suppression feature. And many other examples always a good place to check first. Here is another example of mine written in [Kotlin](https://github.com/perkss/kotlin-kafka-and-kafka-streams-examples/blob/master/kotlin-kafka-streams-examples/src/test/kotlin/com/perkss/kafka/reactive/examples/AggregateExamplesTest.kt#L76).

An explanation of the feature and testing it can be found in post 3 on this [blog post](https://perkss.github.io/#/DistributedSystems/Streaming#KafkaStreamsKotlin)

Some key points:

- The window will only emit the final result as expected from the documents.
- To flush the final results you will need to send an extra dummy event as seen in the examples such as confluents [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/window/CustomWindowTest.java#L308).
- You will need to manipulate the event time to test it as suppression works off the event time this can be provided by the test input topic [API](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TestInputTopic.html#pipeInput-K-V-java.time.Instant-) or use a custom *TimestampExtractor*.
- For testing I recommend setting the following to remove cache and reduce commit interval.

  props[StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG] = 0
  props[StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG] = 5

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the examples, really helped me out with a project I'm working on atm